# AWS DocumentDB collection lock due to change stream log truncating process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, changestream

I am using change stream from my application on document DB collections. And It is experiencing periodical failure (around 20 days) and it is due to change stream log clearing process and AWS is locking those collections for an hour to clean the logs. How can I resolve this issue?

1. Restarting the application  - this is not resolving issue until 1 hour get over
2. Restarting the application before the issue occurring - this did not help